# Start gnome-terminal with interactive program

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to get [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/), an interactive fuzzy finder, running in a new terminal when calling a particular keyboard shortcut. In a traditional terminal window, I either call `fzf` or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch it. My problem is that I'm unable to reproduce this programmatically (so that I can assign it to a Gnome keyboard shortcut). `gnome-terminal --command="fzf"` tells me it couldn't find a process named `fzf`. `gnome-terminal --command="xdotool key ctrl+t"` doesn't do anything but does work if I call it from an open terminal window. Changing the profile preference that says the terminal should stay open after the command is run results in the terminal saying "the child process has ended with a 0 status". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `declare -f fzf` gave me exactly what I needed, thanks! You want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fzf is a shell function. That's why you can't just run it directly.

You would need to run your shell (possibly in interactive mode) to get the function to exist.

Alternatively find out (i.e declare -f fzf in your shell) what command is actually being run and run that directly.